# Find the child of the element represented by "this" that has a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I know how to accomplish this if I can identify this element using a `selector`:

```
$("selector.class")
```

But what if my selector is the keyword `this`? Obviously `$(this".class")` isn't going to work, and I don't want to use `$(this).children(".class")` because then I need to extract the HTML of the element using `.html()`, and while I know that there will only be one element of this class in the selected element (I'm writing the HTML), JQuery doesn't, and it assumes that `children()` returns several elements when used with a class (at lease I think that's what it does, because

```
$(this).children(".class").html()
```

returns `undefined`).

Is there an other way I could do this?

Please feel free to ask for clarification, I understand this may not seem clear to some.

**EDIT**: some of you asked for clarification, so here it is. Let me rephrase the question: normally, when I ask JQuery to get me some elements, and give it a class as a selector it assumes I will get more than one element back and therefore `$(".selector").html()` doesn't work, because you can't get the HTML of several elements (at least that's my theory). Instead, I want it to recognise that in this case I am only getting 1 element back, and treat is as such. My restriction is that part of my selector is `this`. I hope that helped!

Comment: one of your comment suggests you want to select children of selector with class 'class' therefore your original selector should have been `selector .class`  meaning you can use find rather than filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear to me what question you're asking so here are several different options:

To search for any subordinate tags (in the DOM tree with `this` as its root) that match a desired selector:

```
$(this).find(".myClass");
```

Or, if you're just trying to see if the `this` element has a particular class name, you can use:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("myClass")) {
    // this element has the desired class
}
```

or, if the selector is more complicated than just a class, you can use `.is()` like this:

```
if ($(this).is("selector")) {
    // this element matches desired selector
}
```

Comment: What's the difference (if any) between `filter()` and `find()`?

Comment: @Bluefire - `filter()` reduces the number of elements in the current jQuery object to only the ones that match the selector.  `find()` searches the subordinate tags for any that match the selector.  You use `.find()` if you're searching a tree.  You use `.filter()` to remove elements from the current jQuery object that area already in that jQuery object.

Comment: `$(this).find(".lesson").html()` returns undefined. Is there a way to do this that treats the returned elements as one element if there only is one (as I asked in the question)?

Comment: `.filter()` applies the current selection, while `.find()` searches child elements. `$(‘td’).filter(expr)` will remove any `td`s that don’t match the filter criteria. `$(‘td’).find(‘span’)` will find `span`s inside `td`s. This is functionally similar to `$(‘td span’);`.

Comment: Doesn't he want to use `.filter` and not `.find`?  Look at his original selector

Comment: @ExplosionPills - the question is not particularly clear in that regard.  If `this` is a single element, it would be odd to do `$(this).filter()`.  The other options I've offered would make more sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

Really `this` isn't a selector, but I think you can do:

```
$(".class", this)
```

This is an example of supplying the `context` argument to [the `jQuery` (`$`) function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

For example ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/et9R7/2/)),
HTML:

```
<div id="dis">hello
    <div class="cls">
        hi</div></div>
<div class="cls">
    goodbye</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#dis').click(function () {
        alert(
            $('.cls', this).html());
    });
});
```

will alert "hi" when the "dis" div is clicked.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, yes?  I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: I think you need to have is $(this,'.class');

Comment: @StorefrontDoors, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/Nsx93/)?  If that's the case I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I tried to update it, but i could not get it to save; however, you need to place the .dis close tag after the .cls div. The .dis object needs to wrap all child elements that it is the parent of. <div id="dis">hello
    <div class="cls">
        hi</div>
<div class="cls">
    goodbye</div></div>

Answer (score 1):

Jquery is just a layer on top of JavaScript.

Just use raw javascript to get what you're looking for.

```
var childOfThis = this.querySelector('.myClass');
```